# JavaScript Regex Positive Lookahead no immediate follow up of the Term

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I try to create a regex pattern which captures links.

The Term which I search e.g. "another" is not immediatly followed up by the link. There is random HTML text inbetween.

After that there is a link which I want to capture.

Is it possible for regular expression to find the link immediately?

I tried it with positive lookahead but I learned that it should be immediatly followed by the given term which in this case isn't true.

Here are my 2 "Test pages".

https://macrofan.lima-city.de/testpage.html

https://macrofan.lima-city.de/testpage2.html

Comment: Are you searching in a html dom tree / loaded website or in a html text that was (for example) returned by an ajax request? Do you want to get the tag id of the anchor element, the anchor (dom)element itself or just the html text for that tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the first link, you can use this RegExp:

```
another.*"([a-zA-Z-]*\.html)"
```

This assumes that your links are set like in your example, otherwise you would have to modify this before the capturing group to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all href attibutes by using..

```
var m = htmlString.match(/href="([^\'\"]+)/g)
```

It will return array of all href matches.
Once you have the array, you can fetch first or last link whatever you want.